# Is there any STL in C++ to get a sub array from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

user want to get a subarray of a given array without using iterative function .
Is there any STL function present or any shortcut ?
It will help to reduce code complexity.

I don't know the exact methodology to solve this problem .
I expect someone to help me out to tackle this problem efficiently.

Comment: Yes there is [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). Note a span is non-owning so the original array must still be there for span to be valid. Otherwise use std::array or std::vector and you can create new instances using iterators to begin and end of the data you want to copy. Next time also provide an example of your current code, because we cannot see if you use "C" style arrays or not (which you shouldn't)